# How should I set up a web project using Kotlin on the back-end and in the browser?

Tags: kotlin

If I wanted to build a website which used Kotlin both on the back-end, and in the browser - how would I set this up?  Is there a Maven archetype or a Gradle template that captures best-practices for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to keep the modules separate, and I guess conceptually you'd probably want to do that also. While IntelliJ IDEA for instance doesn't natively support the ability to output to JS and JVM with Kotlin, in principle with Gradle/Maven you could. Here are instructions on targeting JVM and JavaScript for Gradle http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: Thank you.  I do want to use Gradle to build the project, due to continuous integration and automated deployment.  Will the "kotlin" and "kotlin2js" plugins clash if used in the same Gradle build file?

Comment: I've not tried it. I don't think it will crash, but please let us know if any issues.